# What is the UX on an ANDROID device for the user hitting a maps.apple.com location link?

Tags: ios, maps

I can't find anything else on this topic, but suggested links are appreciated :)

A piece of code I'm reviewing, on an iPhone but *without* Apple Maps (which was deleted), is written as follows: http://maps.apple.com/?q=1.541354,104.265101

On a DESKTOP DEVICE (because the site I'm hitting is a responsive design), that link works and redirects to the intended destination, but does so on GOOGLE MAPS (since Apple Maps is a native iOS app and doesn't have a desktop web version).

HOWEVER, on my Apple 6s running latest iOS 12.0 variant, where I (like millions of other iOS users) have long-since deleted APPLE MAPS so as to make Google Maps my default, the screen shot that I pasted below appears:

[REINSTALL APPLE MAPS message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqcxs.png)

Here is the text:

"Restore 'Maps'? 
You followed a link that requires the app "Maps", which is no longer on your iPhone. You can restore it from the App Store.

[OPTIONS] Show in App Store Cancel"

SO, contrary to the upvoted answer from 2014 above, the maps.apple.com link does NOT redirect on Apple iPhones.

IT does redirect on desktop.

QUESTION 1: What is the UX on an ANDROID device for the user hitting that same link, who of course wouldn't be expected to have APPLE MAPS app installed?

QUESTION 2: What's the solution? The developer has to recode all map links to remove "maps.apple.com" links?

Thoughts?  Thank you.

=======================

Comment: You mention a 2014 answer, I don't see the the link in your question.

Comment: Apologies. It was another post here on StackOverflow.com.